# Maude for Windows

Tags: cygwin, windows-10

I'm trying to install Maude for Windows 10 64 bit using the instructions here http://safe-tools.dsic.upv.es/maude/

I can't get the Cygwin terminal to do what it's supposed to.

> $ cd buddy
>   -bash: cd: buddy: No such file or directory

But the directory is obviously there.

Answer (score 0):

Here are other links that I know work for sure, in case you want to take a look:

[Direct method](http://maude.cs.uiuc.edu/download/)

[For eclipse](http://mdt.sourceforge.net/?q=documentation/installation)

[Maude online compiler](http://maude.cvlad.info/)

Personally I always choose to use the online one.